# How To Make Android Functional Unit Test

Tags: android, unit-testing

I would Like To Make Functional Unit Test For This Method As Example Of Junit4 Test

```
public boolean validatePasswordExpression(String newPassword) {
        int passwordLength = newPassword.length();
        if (passwordLength > 20 || passwordLength < 8)
            return false;

        else return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already read up about [how to create local Unit Tests in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html), since you're only testing the valid length of a `String`, you'll need to check the following scenarios:

- A valid length
- A length that's too short
- A length that's too long
- Lengths on the bounds of acceptability
- A `null` String

So something like this would suffice (assuming your class is called `PasswordChecker`, replace with whatever it's actually called):

```
private PasswordChecker checker;

@Before public void setUp() {
    checker = new PasswordChecker();
}

@Test public void testValidPassword() {
    assertTrue(checker.validatePasswordExpression("validPassword1"));
}

@Test public void testShortPasswordReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(checker.validatePasswordExpression("Short"));
}

@Test public void testNullPasswordReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(checker.validatePasswordExpression(null));
}

@Test public void testLongPasswordReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(checker.validatePasswordExpression("ThisPasswordIsWayTooLongSoTrySomethingElse"));
}

@Test public void testEightCharPasswordReturnsTrue() {
    assertTrue(checker.validatePasswordExpression("IsValid1"));
}

@Test public void testNinteenCharPasswordReturnsTrue() {
    assertTrue(checker.validatePasswordExpression("ThisPasswordIsValid"));
}

@Test public void testTwentyCharPasswordReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(checker.validatePasswordExpression("ThisPasswordIsTwenty"));
}
```

Comment: when i run this TestClass I have error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Put `Looper.prepare()` in the `setUp()` method.